# Find the file extension of the given file name

Tags: php

How to find the extension of given file name:

See code below:

> $file_name = "sample.jpg";

```
Output will be: .jpg
```

I need to find the extension of the file name

Example: If we parse sample.jpg i should return .jpg

Comment: Use `pathinfo()`. And searchbar.

Comment: If my input like sample.jpg.txt??

Comment: Even typing in "file extension" into the search box on http://php.net would have led you on the right path...

Comment: If your input is `sample.jpg.txt` the extension is `.txt`.

Comment: This will have been asked multiple times before. Use the search facility or even Google next time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with explode

```
    $file_name = "sample.jpg";
    $pieces = explode(".", $file_name);
    echo $pieces[0]; // sample
    echo '.'.$pieces[count($pieces)-1]; // .jpg
```

You can also use this:

```
$ext = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
echo $ext;//jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Here one way to find:

```
<?php
$filename = "sample.txt.jpg";
$ext = substr($filename, strrpos($filename, "."));
echo $ext;
?>
```

Comment: Fails weirdly if the name contains no `.`.

Comment: If name does not contains (.) it is not file name.

Comment: LOL! :-D Uhm... no. File names do not *require* an extension. Sorry to disappoint.

Comment: Believe him. I've made this error a long time ago, and the result was katastrophal :-)

Comment: If the user rename like that :)

Comment: Or if the system provide it like that... which means file names do not *require* an extension, and your code needs to consider this!

Comment: Cool :) It is core basic without pathinfo we can. Kinda logic useful for developers

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP SPL class to find any info about a file. more detail [read here](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php)

```
$file = new SplFileInfo($path);
$ext  = $file->getExtension();
```